# Getting access token for google+ with requested permissions

Tags: c#, wpf, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I have been using google+ APIs for C# in my desktop application.I have to access the friends list of the google+ user.

**I have been obtaining access token by extracting it from browser title.**

It works fine for the following permissions(all grouped and asked at same time) and returns the authentication code in browser title(success=authcode).

```
                 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
                 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
                 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"
```

**But when i changed the permission to obtain the friends list,**

```
                 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
```

**it's not returning the desired auth code ,it just returns success authuser=0&promt...**

By the way I can't listen on local web server.
How to obtain the access token by using the above permission?

Comment: Hi..Actually it returns the authentication code in the title bar ,but the format changes.Normally it returns "Success=Authcode" but for the above permission it is returning 
"Success authuser=0&prompt=consent&session_state=96d1b8d6c0d5d49b4e5404e4bfac620f0265c016..acb1&code=AuthCode",So it's not visible in the title bar.Now I am able to extract the authentication code from the title..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked this and the success string in the window title is in fact different when you are using the plus.login scope. The code that is returned in the string is still valid though. The following code shows one way you could extract the authorization code from the window title string:

```
    string pollActiveWindowForAuthCode(int sleepTime){
        string activeTitle = GetActiveWindowTitle();
        while (!activeTitle.StartsWith("Success"))
        {
            activeTitle = GetActiveWindowTitle();
            Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
        }
        // strip to start of auth code
        string trimToAuthCode = activeTitle.Substring(activeTitle.LastIndexOf("=") + 1);
        // trim the " - Google Chrome" text
        return trimToAuthCode.Substring(0, trimToAuthCode.IndexOf(' '));
    }
```

I have uploaded a more comprehensive demo to my GitHub:

[csharp-gplus-wpf](https://github.com/gguuss/csharp-gplus-wpf)

Comment: Thanks @class!!This code works like a charm and I am able to retrieve the authentication code..